# Camera matrix measurement units

Tags: matrix, camera, computer-vision

I'm new in computer vision and i'm finding some troubles about how calibration matrix, rotation matrix and translation vector should be set up before multiply.

Calibration matrix K is expressed in pixel units (focal length and image center)

Rotation matrix R is adimensional

Translation vector T is expressed in world coordinates (e.g. millimeters)

K,R and T are known so how do i build the 3x4 camera matrix K(R|T)?

Is it correct to express K in pixel units and leave T in mm?

Answer (score 1):

T is in mm, but it have to be multiplied by KR:
P = [KR | -KRT];

For details see good lecture on [Geometry for computer vision](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?tok=0b9c50&media=https%3A%2F%2Fcw.fel.cvut.cz%2Fwiki%2F_media%2Fcourses%2Fgvg%2Fpajdla-gvg-lecture-2021.pdf), p.40

Comment: That link doesn't have the content anymore

Comment: I just clicked on it and it still works.

Comment: Weird, I find the link working too, wonder what was wrong back when I made the comment

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, except that the (3,3) element of K, equal to 1, is adimensional, so to get pixel units for the horizontal and vertical image coordinates after doing the perspective division by the third homogeneous coordinate.